# Solution for remote database slow response times

Tags: sql, database, performance, sql-server-express, p2p

We have a Microsoft SQL Server Express set up in Austria. Local queries are fast, as they should be, but when performed from Romania they are very slow due to what we've concluded to be low bandwidth on the Austrian side.

The issue of bandwidth in itself cannot be fixed, but we are currently investigating whether keeping two copies of the same database in both locations would be a solution. As such we've found the concept of Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication, but it requires a payed version of the database.

Could anyone with knowledge regarding databases please tell me if using the P2P Transactional Replication would be a good fix for this issue, of if there is another possibility to address this?

Thank you in advance,

Victor

Comment: If the database is not being updated frequently or you can deal with slightly out-of-date data, just copy the database once per day.  Otherwise, transactional replication may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Out-of-date data is out of the question, so we'll use the replication.

Comment: But transactional replication with a lot of updates are also going to suffer under low bandwidth keep that in mind.